# Rows not being Deleted from Azure CloudTable

Tags: .net-core, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to delete rows from my Azure CloudTable, but the rows are not being deleted. The code executes without errors and I get an HTTP 204 success result. I've tried several methods of deleting these rows, but none of them are actually deleting the rows.

```
            var query = new TableQuery<SearchCompletedEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey"
                    , QueryComparisons.Equal
                    , requestId)); ;
            var result = await _table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);

            var batchDeleteOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
            foreach (var row in result)
            { batchDeleteOperation.Delete(row); }

            await _table.ExecuteBatchAsync(batchDeleteOperation);
```

Comment: `ExecuteBatchAsync` returns an object of type `TableBatchResult`. Can you check what you're getting there?

Comment: @GauravMantri, HttpStatusCode = 204 and Result is the row I'm attempting to delete.

Comment: What's the SDK you're using and how many items are you trying to delete in the batch?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table v1.0.8. This test batch only has 1 item in it, but has the potential to have many -- nowhere near 100 though. I've also tried without using a batch and I get essentially the same result.

Comment: I am able to run your code successfully. Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/gmantri/bb80e33025db9fcfd21177f73aafacf9.

Comment: Many thanks @GauravMantri. I changed my code to initialize my table as you did and my code now works. I was using CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString); cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient().

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind posting your solution as an answer? It will definitely help somebody. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample from Gaurav Mantri, I found that if I changed how I was initializing my table I was able to successfully delete the records. I'm not sure what the specific issue is with the previous code, but wanted to post the change so it may help someone else.

**Previous code that would not allow deleting records**

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(configuration.ConnectionString);
var tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
```

**Updated code that allowed deleting records**

```
var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(configuration.AccountName, configuration.AccountKey);
var tableClient = new CloudTableClient(new Uri(configuration.SearchCompletedTableUrl), storageCredentials);
```